# Show that $P$ is symmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, symmetry, transpose

Let $P$ = $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$, where A is an m x n matrix with rank $n$.

I feel like this is wrong, but here is my attempt:
$A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ = $AA^{-1}(A^T)^{-1}A^T$ = $I$
And $I^T$ = $I$, so the matrix is symmetric.

Comment: What is $(A(A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top)^\top$? Use the facts that $(AB)^\top = B^\top A^\top$ and $(A^{-1})^\top = (A^\top)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is only correct if $n=m$. If $n\not=m$, then $A^{-1}$ does not exist. $P$ is symmetric if $P^T=P$, so that's what you have to show.

$$P^T=\left(A\left(A^TA\right)^{-1}A^T\right)^T=\left(A^T\right)^T \left(\left(A^TA\right)^{-1}\right)^TA^T$$
$$=A\left(\left(A^TA\right)^{T}\right)^{-1}A^T=A\left(A^T\left(A^T\right)^T\right)^{-1}A^T=A\left(A^TA\right)^{-1}A^T=P$$